# SED not matching optional double quotes (")

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to write a bash script to insert the word Test to any line starting with AlarmName:
Example:

```
AlarmName: "Blah"
```

Becomes

```
AlarmName: "TestBlah"
```

The double quotes are optional and here is the command I have so far

```
's/\(AlarmName:\s*("?)\([^"]*\)"?\)/<WHAT GOES HERE>/g' blah.txt > blah2.txt
```

I am running into two issues, the first is I can't seem to get SED to match the optional quotes. And the second issue is I am not sure how to modify text within a capture group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sed -E 's/^AlarmName:\s*"?/&Test/' file
```

It's enough to match the prefix part `AlarmName: "` and replace it with the copy of self (the `&` part), with `Test` text appended.

Or, if you prefer a pure [POSIX BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html):

```
sed 's/^AlarmName:[[:space:]]*"\{0,1\}/&Test/' file
```

Comment: Thanks I had no idea how awesome the & operator was

Comment: Quick question, this works when I do a small file but when I try it with a big file I get the following error "sed: 1: "s/AlarmName:[[:space:]] ...": RE error: invalid repetition count(s)"
Any ideas?

Comment: That's weird, if you figured it out, what was the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
sed 's|^\(AlarmName\s*:\s*\)\("*\)\([^"]*\)\("*\)|\1\2Test\3\4|'
```

You are breaking the input into four sections (`\1`, `\2`, `\3` and `\4`), where:
`\1` represents the `AlarmName:` prefix,
`\2` represents the optional quotation,
`\3` represents the string to prepend `Test` to, and
`\4` represents the closing brace.

Notice the `\`'s before each of the group start/end braces (you missed some of those in your attempt above)